# JDateChooser one day off when getting date from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I have two dates in a MySQL database: 2019-12-04 and 1961-06-11. I retrieve both and set the date on a JDateChooser. The first one displays OK, while the second one is always a day off. ¿Any ideas why this happens?

I set the date like this:

```
// This class has a getConnection() method with connection paameters
Conexion con = new Conexion(); 
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    Connection conexion = con.getConnection(); // connect to DB
    ps = conexion.prepareStatement("select fecha from fechas where id = ?");

    /* 
    This is hardcoded for testing:
    arg = 1 // database: 2019-12-04, displays correctly (my locale: 2019/12/04)
    arg = 2 // database: 1961-11-01, displays one day off (my locale: 10/06/1961)
    */

    ps.setInt(1, arg);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        datePicker.setDate(rs.getDate("fecha"));
    }

    conexion.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
```

Comment: Localisation issue?  What locale is the database using and what locale is your JVM using?  This is why its important to include the timezone with your date values ... I keep saying it, people keep ignoring it ... and I end of having to bury lots of bodies ... opps, did I say that out loud 

Comment: Can you log what the value and data/class type is immediately upon fetching, i.e. `rs.getDate("fecha")`? Then we can tell whether it's the query or the picker that's doing something unexpected. You might have found a bug in the picker, not many folks deal with dates before 1970.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Thanks but localization is not an issue, actually the DB connection take care of that via the "servertimezone" property (yes, I did know about timezone issues).

Comment: @karmakaze On dates before 1968-10-28 I get a day off. Starting on Oct 28 1968, dates display correctly (Oct 28 displays 1968-10-28, but october 27 displays 1968-10-26, so you never see 1968-10-27). I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: @karmakaze The class is java.sql.date and the value I get is exactly the same value that is displayed on the picker. I guess dig into the source code is the next thing to do.